# How call GDI functions from a CLR project?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am using Visual Studio Express 2012 Desktop. I have a CLR C++ project. I am trying call basic GDI functions like GetDC and DeleteDC. But, I get linker error:

```
Error   8   error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000053) 
"extern "C" struct HDC__ * __stdcall GetDC(struct HWND__ *)" 
(?GetDC@@$$J14YGPAUHDC__@@PAUHWND__@@@Z) referenced in function "int 
__cdecl SaveToFile(struct HBITMAP__ *,wchar_t const *)" 
(?SaveToFile@@$$FYAHPAUHBITMAP__@@PB_W@Z)   
c:\Users\XXX\Main.obj   TestProject
```

What libraries do I need to add to the project, and how? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Shortly after i posted the question I found out the solution. I open project properties. Then went to Configuration properties > Linker > Input. In Additional Dependencies, I added bunch of libraries.

kernel32.lib;user32.lib;gdi32.lib;winspool.lib;comdlg32.lib;advapi32.lib;shell32.lib;ole32.lib;oleaut32.lib;uuid.lib;odbc32.lib;odbccp32.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)

I probably don't need all of them right now, but in future I might.